# Problem in referencing the outportb() function In C

Tags: c, mingw

I have a code in which am trying to use outportb(), but while compiling it on MinGw i am getting below error.

```
C:\Users\A_TOMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYPvctv.o:dsp.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `outportb'
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>

int main(void)
{
  outportb(0x378,0xFF);
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to know which header file is having this particular function?

Comment: `outportb` is a DOS anachronism - even if you could get this to compile it wouldn't work under anything newer than Windows 98.

Comment: How do i achieve same functionality as provided by outportb using MinGW .I on windows7!!

Comment: If you're trying to access the parallel port then you will need to use a more appropriate Windows API.

Comment: Guys i replace this function with _outp and its working fine!!

Comment: MSDN says that this function doesn't work on WinXP and later versions. Did you get it working on your PC?

Comment: Andrey i have replaced the outportb function with _outp function and now am not getting any compilation error related to outportb but still not getting desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Windows doesn't provide access to a hardware. You should use Win32 API calls.
2. This function is DOS specific and unavailable in Windows

Googling shows that your solution is inpout32.dll ([example with weird font color](http://www.hytherion.com/beattidp/comput/pport.htm))

Comment: i really don't know how do i link inpout32.dll with my program.Anyway Thanks for your help.

Comment: with the same function outportb am trying to compile my code but while compiling i am using this options mingw32-gcc.exe dsp1.c  -L ./inpout32.dll  but seeing same thing undefined reference for outportb

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <pc.h>
void outportb(unsigned short _port, unsigned char  _data);
```

Comment: The asker's problem is a linker issue, not a missing function prototype.

Comment: But this pc.h file doesnot come with MinGw compiler??

Comment: Sorry thought you were refering to the djgpp lib. Nevermind :-)